# powershell -replace regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, scripting

I have the following script which I try to run on various html files

```
$files = $args[0];
$string1 = $args[1];
$string2 = $args[2];
Write-Host "Replace $string1 with $string2 in $files";
gci -r -include "$files" | 
 foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) | 
    foreach-object { 
            $_ -replace "%string1" , "$string2" | 
            set-content $a
    }
}
```

in an attempt to edit this line found in all the files.

```
<tr><td><a href="sampleTest.html">TestCase</a></td></tr>
```

I call the script from powershell like this (it's called replace.ps1)

```
./replace *.html sampleTest myNewTest
```

but instead of changing sampleTest.html to myNewTest.html
it deletes everything in the doc except for the last line,
leaving all of the files like so:

```
/html
```

in fact, no matter what arguments I pass in this seems to happen.
Can anyone explain this/help me understand why it's happening?

Answer (score 3):

Your loop structure is to blame here. You need to have the `Set-Content` located outside the loop. Your code is overwriting the file at every pass.

```
....
 foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) | 
    foreach-object { 
            $_ -replace "$string1" , "$string2" |         
    } | set-content $a
}
```

It also might have been a typo but you had `"%string1"` before which, while syntactically correct, what not what you intended.

Could also have used `Add-Content` but that would mean you have to erase the file first. `set-content $a` used at the end of the pipe is more intuitive.

---

Your example is not one that uses regex. You could have used `$_.replace($string1,$string2)` with the same results.